# JSQMessagesViewController custom link not working

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement the answer and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210626/6481734) which is also on the Github [fork](https://github.com/rmelian2014/JSQMessagesViewController/tree/contributing). I'm having many glitches. First, random other messages are becoming links without a '#'. When I scroll up and down those links appear and disappear, but the 'real' '#' links stay. Also, the regular internet links are recognized as links but do not work (send to safari). Could anyone tell me what's causing these and how to fix them?

Screenshot:

[image]

Scroll Down:

[image]

scroll back up:

[image]

Notice the change in links from the top and bottom pictures. The messages that shouldn't be links change back and forth from links and the links that should be links stay. Also the google.com link does not work.

Comment: are you having problems with the code that I provided?

Comment: Yes... I tried to outline those problems as best I could in this question.

Comment: I will review and resolve my code ASAP, sorry for that, I don't test enough

Comment: I added examples of what is going on

Comment: Yes I see the problem, I am working to fixit, and update my fork

Comment: check my fork, was updated, I test and seems its finally ok!, if you find something wrong please let me know

Comment: how do you implement it? addCustomLinkExpression no longer exists

Comment: No, now is implemented with a delegate, check my comment on original answer, again  if you find something wrong please let me know