# NSArray of NSRegularExpressions in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray, nsregularexpression

The fork [here](https://github.com/rmelian2014/JSQMessagesViewController/tree/contributing) has a custom link function but the implementation in the actual code is in objective C.[This](https://github.com/rmelian2014/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/contributing/JSQMessagesDemo/DemoMessagesViewController.m#L572) is the code line and her it is printed again:

```
- (NSArray<NSRegularExpression*>*)getRegularExpressions
{
   return [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#([a-zA-Z0-9])+" options:0 error:NULL]];
}
```

I was wondering how i could reproduce this in swift, I have already placed all of the framework code, I just need to know how to do this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func getRegularExpressions() -> [NSRegularExpression] {
    var arrayOfExpressions = [NSRegularExpression]()
    do
    {
        let expresion = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#([a-zA-Z0-9])+", options:.CaseInsensitive)
        arrayOfExpressions.append(expresion)
    }catch _
    {
        arrayOfExpressions.removeAll()
        return arrayOfExpressions
    }
    return arrayOfExpressions;
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: @Jacolack can you put in my fork a star if I had resolve your problem?, thanks